# Cancel long running queries in HSQLDB / JDBC

Tags: sql, jdbc, hsqldb, cancellation

We have got a large number of long running SQL queries and would like to be able to cancel the execution. So far, I am using an `ExecutorCompletionService` to run the queries, which works well for cancelling queries which are not yet run.

My problem is: I would like to hard-cancel the currently running queries too. The method java.sql.Statement.cancel() does not seem to work with `HSQLDB`. From the [java doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html): "Cancels this Statement object if both the DBMS and driver support aborting an SQL statement." I guess that HSQLDB does not support cancellation.

Does anyone have any idea how to cancel the statement anyways (in a possibly ugly, but still acceptable way)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34094074/how-to-abort-cancel-hsqldb-query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://sourceforge.net/p/hsqldb/bugs/1436/ for a working solution.

The short variant:

Use the newest SVN Version of HSQLDB or the 2.3.4 Final for the Server.

If the current query that you want to cancel is using a hsqldb connection, create a new connection with admin rights to the same server.

Use

`select * from information_schema.system_sessions`

to find the session with the statement you are looking for.

Use

`ALTER SESSION <SESSIONNUMBER> RELEASE`

to cancel the Statement.

Close the Connection.

Answer (score 0):

For me the working sql command was `ALTER SESSION <SESSIONNUMBER> END STATEMENT`