# How to abort/cancel HSQLDB query

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hsqldb

I have a Java SE application using JPA provided by Hibernate and a HSQL database. The application queries the database with EntityManagers for information in order to draw charts on the screen. While the query is executing, the area for the chart has the typical spinning icon to let the user know that it's working. Some queries take a long time, and I want to have the feature to abort/cancel the query. I know I can unwrap the EntityManager and get the Hibernate Session and call cancelQuery(), but that doesn't do anything because the HSQLDB driver doesn't support the cancel() method on the Statement interface (http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/apidocs/org/hsqldb/jdbc/JDBCStatement.html#cancel()). Is there another way either through API or redesigning my app? Not being able to cancel a running query is a nuisance.

Comment: Probably simply interrupting the Thread will work. Don't know how it is handled in HSQLDB though but worth giving a try since it is pretty simple to implement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> At the Moment there is no way to end a long-running Statement on a HSQLDB Server. The ALTER SESSION Method provided by Fredt does not seem to work in the current RC2 for 2.3.4 (and also in the svn revision 5511), it just leads to a transaction rollback:serialization failure AFTER the select statement has finished working. So the only way to deal with this Problem is setting the Timeout. This is not an actual Solution to the Problem, though.

Update: In the newest Version of HSQLDB in the SVN Repository (Rev. 5627) and in the upcoming 2.3.4 Release, the possibility to cancel a statement immediately is now implemented. There also is a new Method, ALTER SESSSION  END STATEMENT, that can abort a transaction without a rollback. See https://sourceforge.net/p/hsqldb/bugs/1436/ for details.

Comment: My thoughts exactly. I've seen those errors as well using the the ALTER SESSION method. Even if no errors were thrown, how am I supposed to know which session id to release? I agree a timeout is not a solution. Some queries naturally take a long time, and there should be a way for the user to cancel a query if they don't want to wait anymore.

Comment: I forgot all about this. Yes, the newer versions of HSQLDB now support canceling queries through the JDBC API. For older versions, I simply just threw the running query into the background, ignored it, and moved on.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a separate connection with admin rights and terminate the transaction in a different session:

```
ALTER SESSION <session number> RELEASE
```

http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/sessions-chapt.html#snc_statements

In the latest Subversion revisions of HSQLDB, this statement also terminates any SELECT statement that is running in the target session.

You can use SESSION_ID() to find the id of the session and use it to release the session.

Also, it is possible to use JDBCStatement.setQueryTimeout(n) before you execute the query.

The cancel() method may be supported in the near future.

Comment: This is HSQLDB specific. Is there not a way through the JPA or JDBC interface to cancel a query? If I used this query, I would have to do it within the application. How would I know which session to release? Is there a way to get and store the session id so I can use it later to submit this query to release it?

Comment: Does this mean that it can only be done if using HSQLDB in server mode (`hsql://`) , and not in local file (`file:`) mode?

Comment: It can be done in both server and embedded mode using a different session.